# Trying to sort array of Strings

Tags: java

I've written the below program to sort input strings, and output a lexicographically sorted list.

There seems to be a problem with it, can someone help me find it?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problem3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String statement = scanner.nextLine();
        screen(statement);
    }
    public static void screen(String statement)  // sorting mechanism 
    {
        String token[]= statement.split(" ");
        String smallestSoFar=token[0]; 
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<token.length;i++)
        {
            smallestSoFar=token[i];
            for(int e=i; e<token.length; e++)
            {
                if(token[e].compareTo(smallestSoFar)<0)  // inputting the // ...lexicographically sorted word into a new list
                {
                    smallestSoFar=token[e]; 
                    list.add(smallestSoFar);                
                }
            }
            System.out.println(list);
        }           
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if any element is followed by a smaller element, it won't be printed out (and the larger element will be printed twice). And your print is in the wrong place (it should be after the loop).

You can simply use

```
Arrays.sort(token)
```

or

```
list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(token));
Collections.sort(list);
```

to sort the array.

If you want to stick to your way, here's how I'd do it:

```
boolean[] checked = new boolean[token.length];
int checkedCount = 0;
while (checkedCount < token.length)
{
    int smallestIndex = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < token.length; i++)
    {
        if (!checked[i] &&
            (smallestIndex == -1 || token[i].compareTo(token[smallestIndex]) < 0))
        {
            smallestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    checked[smallestIndex] = true;
    checkedCount++;
    list.add(token[smallestIndex]);
}
System.out.println(list);
```